# Retrieving element attributes for multiple nodes

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I am having the hardest time figuring this out, I have a XML doc that has multiple nodes with the same name. Within those nodes are even more nodes with same name but different attributes and thats what I want to capture. Here is an example of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TopologyDefinition xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/managementsystems/topologydefinition/2009/11">
    <Topology Name="testenv">
        <DataCenters>
            <DataCenter Name="FL" Type="Active">
                <Machines>
                    <Machine Name="FLVMServer1" VmHost="FLVHost100">
                        <IPBindings>
                            <IPBinding VirtualNetworkType="Data" IP="192.168.0.10" />
                        </IPBindings>
                    </Machine>
                        <Machine Name="FLVMServer2" VmHost="FLVHost200">
                        <IPBindings>
                            <IPBinding VirtualNetworkType="Data" IP="192.168.0.20" />
                        </IPBindings>
                    </Machine>
            </DataCenter>
            <DataCenter Name="RI" Type="Passive">
                <Machines>
                    <Machine Name="RIVMServer1" VmHost="RIVHost100">
                        <IPBindings>
                            <IPBinding VirtualNetworkType="Data" IP="192.168.2.10" />
                        </IPBindings>
                    </Machine>
                        <Machine Name="RIVMServer2" VmHost="RIVHost200">
                        <IPBindings>
                            <IPBinding VirtualNetworkType="Data" IP="192.168.2.20" />
                        </IPBindings>
                    </Machine>
            </DataCenter>
        </DataCenters>
    </Topology>
</TopologyDefinition>
```

I need to capture for all DC's the following:
Machine Name
VmHost
IP

I've tried XPATH, I've tried iterating through each node as well with no luck

```
        ServerInfoClass serverInfo = new ServerInfoClass();
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(FilePath);

        XmlNodeList dcElemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("DataCenter");
        for(int j = 0; j < dcElemList.Count; j++)
        {
            XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Machine");
            for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
            {
                serverInfo.ServerName = elemList[i].Attributes["Name"].Value;
                serverInfo.VmHost = elemList[i].Attributes["VmHost"].Value;

                XmlNodeList ipList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("IPBindings");
                for (int x = 0; x < ipList.Count; x++) ;
                {
                    //serverInfo.IPAddress = ipList[x].Attributes["IP"].Value;
                }
                OutPut(serverInfo.ServerName, serverInfo.VmHost, serverInfo.IPAddress);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put that into an XDocument, you can query it like this:

```
XDocument document = // ... your document.
var ns = document.Root.Name.Namespace;
var results = from dcNode in document.Descendants(ns + "DataCenter")
    let Name = dcNode.Attribute("Name").Value
    let Type = dcNode.Attribute("Type").Value
    let Machines = dcNode.Descendants(ns + "Machine").Select(mNode => 
        new { 
            Name = mNode.Attribute("Name").Value,
            VmHost = mNode.Attribute("VmHost").Value,
            Bindings = mNode.Descendants(ns + "IPBinding").Attributes("IP").Select(x => x.Value).ToArray()
        })
    select new { Name, Type, Machines };
```

I'd recommend making a helper extension method for getting attribute values, which also checks for nulls.

One of the keys here is to remember that your XML elements live in a namespace, and you need to supply the full namespace when querying. That is why it is handy here to extract the `ns` namespace instance from the root node at first.

Answer (score 1):

Your example isn't well-formed. You're missing the `</Machines>` tags.

Another way to get do it is using LINQ to XML:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/managementsystems/topologydefinition/2009/11";
foreach (var machine in XElement.Load(@"c:\mydata.xml").Descendants(ns + "Machine"))
{
    string name = machine.Attribute("Name").Value;
    string vmHost = machine.Attribute("VmHost").Value;

    XElement ipBinding = machine.Descendants(ns + "IPBinding").Single();
    string vnType = ipBinding.Attribute("VirtualNetworkType").Value;
    string ip = ipBinding.Attribute("IP").Value;
}
```

Comment: I get Sequence contains more than one element on XElement ipBinding = machine.Descendants(ns + "IPBinding").Single();

This is resolved using FirstOrDefault() instead

Comment: Any suggestions on how to handle null?

Comment: I chose Single() as an example because it matched your sample. FirstOrDefault() is fine as long as the first one is the correct one. You'll have to consider how to handle the null default as well as choosing the correct one if there are multiple ipBinding elements.

Comment: You have to test for null before trying to use an element or attribute. If an element is required then you now get to throw an exception.

Comment: How come this does not loop through both datacenters?

Comment: It loops through all machine elements, ignoring datacenters. If grouping by datacenter is important, then loop through a list of datacenter elements and then loop through each datacenter's machine descendants.